# Java Hash Collection

Tags: java, collections

There is a class called HashSet in Java

For example, I'll add following int-shaped value to HashSet,

[input]

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,1,
```

[hash structure]

```
1,1,1
2,2
3,3
4
5
6
```

Is there the collection to become such a structure?

Comment: We call that "thing" a class.  And the language is Java, not JAVA.

Answer (score 7):

If I understand your question properly, you're looking for what's called a "Multiset". Java has no builtin Multisets, but you could build what you want with a `HashMap<Integer, HashSet<Integer>>`. There's also a number of third-party libraries for this, such as the [Google Collections Library](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html).

Comment: If your key is the number, what you really want as the value is just the count of how many are found.

Comment: It's unclear from the question whether he's really storing integers, or if he's storing some more complex objects, and just used integers as an example...

Comment: Actually, I'd say it is clear from the way that question is posed that the OP *expects* the data structure to hold multiple values, rather that indicative values (keys) and counts. Whether that is what he really needs is a different question of course.

Answer (score 6):

No, but it's easy enough to wrap around a HashMap.

```
public class Tally<T> {
  private final Map<T, Integer> count = new HashMap<T, Integer>();

  public void increment(T t) {
    Integer i = count.get(t);
    count.put(t, i == null ? 1 : i+1);
  }

  public void decrement(T t) {
    Integer i = count.get(t);
    if (i == null) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("not present");
    }
    if (i == 1) {
      count.remove(t);
    } else {
      count.put(t, i-1);
    }
  }

  public int get(T t) {
    Integer i = count.get(t);
    return i == null ? 0 : i;
  }
}
```

Comment: You could even override add and delete to create an entry at that key if it didn't exist, and increment if it did.